# How to query_posts after the current timestamp and sort reverse chronologically?

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, custom-post-type

I am using the following code in Wordpress to query events (custom post type) and order them by date chronologically..

`query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'events', 'showposts' => 10, 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num','meta_key' => '_ecmb_datetime' ) );`

Where the meta key `_ecmb_datetime` is, this is the timestamp of the event.

I don't want to show events that have already happened, so my question is how do I only show events happening after my current time, and how do I sort reverse chronologically?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a WP expert, but in checking out a few resources in the Codex, it seems like you have some options. [This page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) seems to suggest not directly altering query_posts, but if you know what you're about, so be it. [This page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) and [this one](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) together suggest ways of modifying the query to order by arbitrary fields through a wrapper of the main function.

I might try something like:

```
function get_pending_events( $query ) {
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
    $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
    $query->set( 'meta_value', time() );
    $query->set( 'meta_compare', '>=' );
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'get_pending_events' );
```

Your date format needs might be different, but this might be one way to go about it. The Codex does seem to have a lot of good info.

Comment: Great! This worked great with one exception - my current date is October 19th 2013, and I have an *event* on October 19th 2013 (so, today) but for some reason this query returns the first event *after* today. My query code is this: `'post_type' => 'events', 'showposts' => 10, 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'meta_key' => '_ecmb_datetime', 'meta_value' => date('U'), 'meta_compare' => '>='`

Comment: Before you ask, yes both today's event timestamp and my blog's current time timestamp return October 19th 2013. I should add that my (current) time is 3:32pm, and the event's timestamp has a time of 8:00pm if that makes any difference. So confused.

Comment: So, when you look at the numeric value of the event timestamp in the database, is it really greater than what you get from `date('U')` right now? I've seen strange timezone issues happen with Date objects and that would be my first guess, but I'm not sure how that would be expressed here.

Comment: Hmm. My blog's current timestamp is `1382222858` and the event's timestamp is `1382212800`, which (if I can see properly) makes the blog's date higher. Dang. This timestamp is returned with `date('U')` and `time()`. Any suggestions?

Comment: As a temporary fix, although I'm not comfortable with it, I've used yesterday's date: `strtotime('-1 day', date('U'))`